# Why does it take so long for some (popular?) wiki tag edits to be reviewed

Tags: support

I've noticed that for most wiki tag edits, it takes only a few hours to get them reviewed (approved and/or rejected). However, right now I have 1 such wiki tag edit suggestion which is being reviewed for about 2 days now (with 1 **reject** about **2 days ago**, followed by **1 approve** about **1 day later**). Those of you who are authorized to "review" (see?) my suggestions should be able to find the specific tag suggestion I'm waiting for now (for about 2 days, fingers crossed ...). I do not want to mention the specific tag suggestion here, to not influence the review process.

I'd like to better understand if there is something like "happening behind the scenes" (not visible to me), like some type of escalation, or some discussion between reviewers. Especially because this specific case is about a reject, followed by an approve, and probably the next judgement will make that tag edit suggestion be approved or rejected.

FYI: I seem to remember that some days ago, for some other (popular) tag something similar happened ... And I think in the end it got ... approved.

PS: Should I consider "flagging" my suggested tag edit, to avoid something like "starvation"? Or is their some procedure in place so that the appropriate reviewer(s) gets reminded with something like "waiting your review"? By editing this question here (1 day after I asked it), I hope to somehow ring a bell somewhere about it also ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to better understand if there is something like "happening behind the scenes" (not visible to me)

The only options we have that would be a discussion here, on meta, or in chat. You can see both of those, so there's nothing behind-the-scenes as such. Obviously if people are collaborating on this stuff outside of the site we wouldn't know, but that's probably quite unlikely.

I'm going to take a stab at guessing why the particular edit you're referring to hasn't been approved yet:

I just read through it and thought "what did this edit do to actually improve the wiki?" Yes you've extended the existing json code example, and added a comparison to yaml, but what does the edit you've suggested do to actually help someone understand *what json is*, and how it is used in Drupal, better than what was already there?

As an aside, you've also included unrelated "meta" information:

> The [yaml](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yaml) tag should become another related tag (after it gets created), consider using [YAML][4] as a temporary alternative for it.

That alone could arguably, theoretically, be grounds for rejection, as it doesn't have anything to do with JSON as a tag.

I'm being intentionally quite picky there, so please don't take offence, but I had to be in order to answer:

> Why does it take so long for some (popular?) wiki tag edits to be reviewed

I think it's because people tend to sit on the fence when they're not sure. I'm among them, I wouldn't be happy approving or rejecting your edit in its current form, as I can't decide whether or not the edit improves the wiki or not (this is my problem, not yours, but it might help to explain others' motivations too).

> Should I consider "flagging" my suggested tag edit, to avoid something like "starvation"?

You can, but unless something's actually gone *wrong* with the process, be prepared for it to be declined. Sometimes these things just have to be waited out.

Bottom line: what you're doing (organising, cleaning, improving) is greatly appreciated, please don't stop it because of frustrations with how long it's taking :)

Comment: Thank you Clive, now "that" is the kind of feedback and answers "I" like to see and read. I fully understand and agree with what you wrote, and I love "constructive" feedback as you wrote. Only 1 thing I (technically) disagree with, I believe JSON and YAML "are" related, which is why I suggested that 'JSON syntax is a basis of YAML version 1.2, which brings YAML "into compliance with JSON as an official subset";'. If for that phrase (only) the entire suggestion would get rejected, then I'd be a bit disappointed (that it 'all' got rejected). See my point? Let's find a way to remove it then.

Comment: Yeah I was being particularly picky with the YAML reference, I don't personally think it needs to be removed. Just pointing out that others might see it as a reason for rejection. Throughout the network a philosophy of "if there's _anything_ wrong with the edit, it's grounds for rejection" has come about over the last couple of years, and I've seen things rejected for much, much less. It's not ideal, but it does work most of the time. And when it doesn't, we have this platform for talking it through

Comment: I'm on mobile at the moment so it's difficult to find any links, I'll have a look later. Suffice to say that the onus is put on the person making the edit to ensure guidelines are met, the person reviewing is essentially just validating that. A reviewer can "improve" the edit as they see fit instead of just rejecting, but that can lead to bad blood and arguments (I've watched it happen). And people don't always understand intent, so they leave it. The system isn't perfect, and there are times when it fails, but I don't know that there's a better automated solution than what we have

Comment: Roger! I mean "OK", I fully understand! PS: I'm on mobile too, can you tell?

Comment: Not trying to hurry/push anything, but just a friendly ping that for a few days quite a few similar edits keep hanging in a similar status. Related question though: is there some kind of limit for tags, similar to question, ie: "you can only ask 30 questions in the last 50 days"?

Comment: Update: shortly after I wrote my prior comment, all outstanding suggestions got decided (so rejected, but hey ...), great! I then submitted another 6 or so suggestions ... none of them have had even 1 review decission so far. So I keep wondering if there is any type of limitation to only suggest X wiki edits in Y hours/days ...

Comment: After about 2 days of waiting for another 6 suggested tag edits, not even 1 of them have received even 1 review (approve or reject). So just waiting and doing nothing does not seem to really work. I'm now considering to submit like 20 more tag edit suggestions, to see what would happen ...

Comment: You need to be patient. These things sometimes take time, it depends on who's available to review. This isn't something a moderator is really needed for, the community will handle it in due course

Comment: OK @Clive , will do so. Do you see any problem if I submit "some" more?

Comment: None at all, go for it

Answer (score 2):

Normal edit reviews can be done by a user with 2000 reputation, for tag edits you need 3000 reputation. Less people have 3000, so it takes longer. See the [help page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) on privileges for that information.
(The 2000 is not so clear, but I found that after googling: when you can edit posts directly you can also other reviewing them).